# Chessboard string

Tags: javascript, for-loop

I have a question about how this JS code produces the chessboard in a string.  I'm not sure how the condition in the  `if` statement is working exactly.

`x + y`  `%` divided by `2` is `===` to `0` is a condition that evaluates to `true`. What I am a little confused about is how it evaluates to true? Can use a little more explaining.

```
var boardSize = 8;
var boardString = '';
// loops to calc y and x axis hash placement
for (var y = 0; y < boardSize; y++){
    for (var x = 0; x < boardSize; x++) {
        // x + y divided by 2 is === to 0
        if ((x + y) % 2 === 0){
            // true add hashes to string
            boardString += ' ';
        } else {
            boardString += '#';
        }
    }
    // newline for each set of hashes
    boardString += '\n';
}
console.log(boardString);
```

Comment: The comment is misleading, `(x + y) % 2 === 0` means "if the remainder of the division of the x+y by 2 is zero".

Answer (score 1):

Aside from a misleading comment, there are a couple of typos in the code:

`boardSize += ' ';` should be `boardString += ' ';`

and

`(var x = 0; y < boardSize; x++)` should be `(var x = 0; x < boardSize; x++)`

---

If you think of a chessboard in terms of the values of `x` and `y` in each square (using the notation `y,x`);

```
0,0 0,1 0,2 ... 0,7
1,0 1,1 1,2 ... 1,7
2,0 2,1 2,2 ... 2,7
 .   .   .
 .   .   .
 .   .   .
7,0 7,1 7,2 ... 7,7
```

What you want is alternate black and white squares. From the above you can see that a square is white if the sum of `x` and `y` is even, and black if odd.

`a % 2 === 0` is `true` if `a` is even (that's how the remainder operator `%`) works.

Hence `((x + y) % 2 === 0)` implies a white square.

Comment: Also, one more fatal typo:  for (var x = 0; y < boardSize; x++)...should be: or (var x = 0; x < boardSize; x++).

Comment: @Bathsheba so from what I am understanding if the sum of `x` and `y` is even such as `4` then a white square is placed down on the board. What I find a little confusing is that I need to check if it is `===` to `0`

Comment: `=== 0` is checking if the bit on the left hand side is *even*.

Comment: Why not use your debugger to inspect the value of `(x + y) % 2` on each step? It will be clear to you then.

Answer (score 1):

as any coordinate for example;

```
          n-1,m
n,m-1     n,m     n,m+1
          n+1,m
```

calculate the sum

```
          n+m-1
n+m-1     n+m     n+m+1
          n+m+1
```

then we do `%2`

```
      1                         0
1     0     1      or     0     1     0
      1                         0
```

expand it

```
1 0 1 0 1 0 1               0 1 0 1 0 1 0
0 1 0 1 0 1 0               1 0 1 0 1 0 1
1 0 1 0 1 0 1       or      0 1 0 1 0 1 0     
0 1 0 1 0 1 0               1 0 1 0 1 0 1
1 0 1 0 1 0 1               0 1 0 1 0 1 0
```

actually, they are the same and you've got a chess board

Answer (score 0):

So the `if` statement is considered a white square because the sum of `x`  and `y` is even.

```
var boardSize = 8;
var boardString = '';
// loops to calc y and x axis hash placement
// think of x and y as white and black squares
// white square = x and y are even. black square = odd.
for (var y = 0; y < boardSize; y++){
    for (var x = 0; x < boardSize; x++) {
        // x + y is true if the remainder of the division is even
        // even = a white square
        if ((x + y) % 2 === 0){
            // true add hashes to string
            boardString += ' ';
        } else {
            boardString += '#';
        }
    }
    // newline for each set of hashes
    boardString += '\n';
}
console.log(boardString);
```

Answer (score 0):

Consise version of the loop:

```js
for (var y = 0; y < boardSize; y++)
  for (var x = 0; x < boardSize; x++)
     boardString += ' #'[(x+y) % 2]
```